# Which are the advantages of developing in Java a server-side application compared to other languages?

Tags: java

Our company is starting the development of a client-server application and a discussion is going on about which technologies should be used. 
For the client (GUI) side we tend to QT and C++. For the server side, we have been advised to use Java and indeed it looks like it is one of the languages being used most for server development. 
Can anyone elaborate on the advantages offered by Java for server side development and why adopting it should make our life as developers easier and/or allow us to reach better results than if we used, let´s say, .NET or even C++?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you intend for your client GUI to interact with the server? CORBA? RMI? SOAP/REST? Whether or not Java holds any advantage for your situation depends heavily on how you intend to use it.

Comment: @yock: basically, all options you suggested are open for now. Since for a first step communication won´t be very complicated even TCP/IP could be an option. I will be glad to accept further suggestions about this point too.

Answer (score 5):

Some advantages:

- Run compiled code across platforms.
- Managed memory (garbage collection).
- Hude wealth of excellent open-source libaries.
- Large developer market.
- Easy migration for C++ developers.

Some disadvantages:

- Aging language — has not kept up with language advances IMO (e.g. adding functional facilities).
- Future uncertain after Oracle aquistion (will become clearer with time).
- Low level programming difficult.

You may want to look also at other languages which run on the JVM, such as Scala and Groovy, at .NET (it can run on Linux et al using Mono) and even the D language, which provides a C++ like, compiled to native, language with modern features such as garbage collection (optional), code contracts, lambdas etc. These languages provide many of the benefits of Java over C/C++ but have also taken the progression a bit further or in different directions.

Comment: I strongly dieagree with aging argument - Java evolves, e.g. for mentioned functional constructs: http://javac.info/ ).

Also the argument with Oracle looks to me exaggerated, and I am not fan of Oracle.

Comment: Disagree with low level programming as well.  You can programming with particual machine instructions you expect the code to JIT to, but for 99.9% of applications you just don't need it.

Comment: @binary_runner: the Java Class Library evolves, the Java language has been pretty much left to stagnate. If you compare evolution with C#, for example, you'll see the Java language hasn't really moved all that much since 1.1 (whether this is a good or bad thing depends upon your language complexity standpoint, but Java is not a desperately uniform language anyhow, though it was compared to C++ which was its main competition at inception).

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I was refering more to low-level, binary protocol type work -- networking, interfacing with devices, &c. The lack of unsigned types and insistence in promoting bytes to integers are both infuriating features.

Comment: There is rarely a good reason to promote unsigned types esp for networking, you can just use the signed version, sometimes with small modificiations.  In any case using an int local variable which could be a byte is a notional problem IMHO. Was +1 btw.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from platform independence, the main advantage of server-side Java development is the wide selection of mature libraries and standardized frameworks. However, the main focus here is on web development.

For a C++ client, Java could still be beneficial if you use REST as protocol between client and server (JAX-RS is pretty nice). Otherwise, it depends very much on your application domain and whether there are Java libraries that could help you in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put it this way... it's not which server-side language is better and what not, it is what's available in your company that you can leverage of and make good use of it. When you work in a big corporation, sometimes you cannot just introduce "yet another language"... it doesn't work that way. :)

Further, every language has its pros and cons. You can almost argue the pros/cons in both way depending on how biased or open-minded you are. You can choose RoR and all that bleeding age technologies, but if your team members are not comfortable in dealing a brand new language, how exactly are you going to maintain the project in long run? I mean, if your team is familiar with PHP, I don't see anything wrong using that compared to Java, .NET, etc.

Your customers don't care the underlying implementation as long as it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The team which will work at this project will be hired also based on the technologies which are going to be used, so we have great freedom for this decision. We are very open minded, and looking for the best solution for our system.

Answer (score 1):

Java advantages:
 - mature
 - good to excellent backward compatibility
 - wide range of available frameworks for almost any problem
 - robust - garbage collection, APIs as java.util.concurrent
 - great tools to manage code quality, good IDEs etc.
 - very good performance
 - support for scripting

disadvantages:
 - sometimes too many frameworks for the same thing
 - not all the frameworks have as good quality of code as you need
 - looks easier than really it is

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of general advantages and disadvantages of Java compared to other languages. My question was aimed more precisely to practical reasons for server side deployment of Java applications. For example, suggestions about which available  frameworks would offer an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options in server side. Since you have the control over server side you can basically use anything. Using .NET forces you to use Windows Server so i will prefer a framework that can run on any operating system and is portable.

Java was the right answer 5-10 years ago. Because it had portability, and can work on any system. But these days developers look for languages/frameworks that are easier to use, maintain and code. I will vote on Python these days for server side development because of this, its fast it easier to read and maintain code wise, and it has many open source projects/libraries that you can use, even Google is favoring python over Java(GAE had python support first, then support for Java came).  You can use django on python for web development and twisted for writing a server that uses TCP to communicate.

Comment: One can run .NET on Linux and other platforms using the Mono project.

Comment: @Paul Ruane .NET is already lacks on features when compared to newer languages/frameworks and MONO even more lacks behind since its like 1-2 years behind decent .NET version.

Comment: in terms of the core language, [it is not so bad](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues you need taken in accout to select the language:

- which are the languages which know your team best / good enougth
- which are the languages which know the team thet must maintain the server
- are there the right frameworks **with an quality that makes you want to use them**
- will the code be maintainable as long as the server is in production
- how fast will be the development -- the importent thing here is not the time you spend to type the code - more important is **the time that you need until the product works stable enougth to use it for production** without reasonable bugs
- communication with other systems - if every system you need to communicate with is an .net - that it would be wise to build the new system in .net too
- are there any constraints (must use this server, open source policy of your company, ...)
- cost of licences, ...
- ...

At least the descicion to use a specific language for an project with a reasonable size, is always the question of cost. But not only the cost to build the system, also the cost to maintain it. - The points mentioned above are all cost related: for example: if you do not knwo the language you are slower (-> $), if the system can not be maintained, it must be rebuiled (-> $), if there are not the right libs, you need to implemnt it by your own (-> $), if the language you picked make it easy for bugs to hide, you need a long time until the system can go in production (-> $)

*In MHO, the advantages of Java are: the wide spread knowlege (this is for .net too), a huge amount of realy mature open source framworks (this is the point for Java against .net), and the usage of a strong typed system and a compiler wich result in less bugs is a long term advantage of Java and .net over every not strong typed scripting language)*

One must have for all languages you use on a Server is an Garbage collection!